# How to update a POM dependency version via command line

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a project that I want to automate its deployment. By default, i want to to grab the LATEST version of a dependency, but on occasion I want to specify the version of the dependency.

This is what I have defined in my POM file:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <MyDep.version>LATEST</MyDep.version>
</properties>
```

Then for the dependency:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>net.org</groupId>
     <artifactId>MyDep</artifactId>
     <version>${MyDep.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

So from my understanding I can override the MyDep.version value via commandline by doing the following:

> mvn clean install -DMyDep.version=2.0.0.0

and that should override LATEST to 2.0.0.0, however it keeps grabbing latest, the property value doenst seem to be updating. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to just use an XML transform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the:

```
mvn versions:use-dep-version
```

command